# Reciclar (optimizar) codigo js de DataTables

Tags: javascript

tengo un codigo js en el cual establezco, configuro y poblo unas DataTables, tambien establezco la configuracion para los plugins necesarios para exportar en pdf,excel,csv e imprimirlo, mi pregunta es si existiria alguna forma para optimizar mi codigo, ya que se repite mucho codigo, a continuacion todo el codigo:

```
$.when($.ready).then(function(){
    $(".export a").click(function() {
        var i = $(this).attr('id');
        var table = $('.tab-pane.active table').DataTable();
        switch (i) {
            case 'csv':
                table.button('.buttons-csv').trigger();
              break;
            case 'excel':
                table.button('.buttons-excel').trigger();
              break;
            case 'pdf':
                table.button('.buttons-pdf').trigger();
              break;
            case 'print':
                table.button('.buttons-print').trigger();
              break;
            default:
          }
    });
    $('#dataTable1').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 15],
        "language": { url : window.location.origin+'/js/tools/datatable_traduction.json' },
        "ajax": window.location.origin+"/dashboard/products/products_list",
        "columns":[
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'stock'},
            {data: 'status_stock'},
            {data: 'price'},
            {data: 'category'},
            {data: 'link'},
            
            
        ],

        dom: "Blfrtip",
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'csv',
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'excel',
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'pdf',
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'print',
                        extend: 'print',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    
                ],
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    targets: -1
                }] 
    });

    $('#dataTable2').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 15],
        "language": { url : window.location.origin+'/js/tools/datatable_traduction.json' },
        "ajax": window.location.origin+"/dashboard/products/products_lowstock_list",
        "columns":[
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'stock'},
            {data: 'status_stock'},
            {data: 'price'},
            {data: 'category'},
            {data: 'link'},
        ],

        dom: "Blfrtip",
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'csv',
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'excel',
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'pdf',
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'print',
                        extend: 'print',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    
                ],
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    targets: -1
                }] 
    });

    $('#dataTable3').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        lengthMenu: [5, 10, 15],
        "language": { url : window.location.origin+'/js/tools/datatable_traduction.json' },
        "ajax": window.location.origin+"/dashboard/products/products_disabled_list",
        "columns":[
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'stock'},
            {data: 'status_stock'},
            {data: 'price'},
            {data: 'category'},
            {data: 'link'},
        ],

        dom: "Blfrtip",
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'csv',
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'excel',
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'pdf',
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'print',
                        extend: 'print',
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
                        }
                    },
                    
                ],
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    targets: -1
                }]

    });
});
```

Tengo varios archivos js parecidos, entre todos los archivos solo varian las partes donde le entrego la ruta al json y las columnas del DataTable:

```
"ajax": window.location.origin+"/dashboard/products/products_list",
        "columns":[
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'stock'},
            {data: 'status_stock'},
            {data: 'price'},
            {data: 'category'},
            {data: 'link'},
            
            
        ],
```

Esas lineas de codigo son las unicas que varian, como podria reciclar el resto del codigo?

Comment: Podrias crear una funcion(donde metes tu codogo de DT) y parametrizar esos valores que varian.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo asi, a ver si funciona y te vale:

```
$.when($.ready).then(function() {
  $(".export a").click(function() {
    var i = $(this).attr('id');
    var table = $('.tab-pane.active table').DataTable();
    switch (i) {
      case 'csv':
        table.button('.buttons-csv').trigger();
        break;
      case 'excel':
        table.button('.buttons-excel').trigger();
        break;
      case 'pdf':
        table.button('.buttons-pdf').trigger();
        break;
      case 'print':
        table.button('.buttons-print').trigger();
        break;
      default:
    }
  });

  let iterable = new Map([
    ["1", "/dashboard/products/products_list"],
    ["2", "/dashboard/products/products_lowstock_list"],
    ["3", "/dashboard/products/products_disabled_list"]
  ]);

  for (let [key, value] of iterable) {
    $('#dataTable' + key).DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      autoWidth: false,
      lengthMenu: [5, 10, 15],
      "language": {
        url: window.location.origin + '/js/tools/datatable_traduction.json'
      },
      "ajax": window.location.origin + value,
      "columns": [{
          data: 'name'
        },
        {
          data: 'stock'
        },
        {
          data: 'status_stock'
        },
        {
          data: 'price'
        },
        {
          data: 'category'
        },
        {
          data: 'link'
        },


      ],

      dom: "Blfrtip",
      buttons: [{
          text: 'csv',
          extend: 'csvHtml5',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'excel',
          extend: 'excelHtml5',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'pdf',
          extend: 'pdfHtml5',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'print',
          extend: 'print',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)'
          }
        },

      ],
      columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        targets: -1
      }]
    });
  }
});
```